# Get mayavi working with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, mayavi

I'm having trouble running mayavi in python 3.3

When running my program with python3 (or python3.3) i get

```
from mayavi import mlab as ml
ImportError: No module named 'mayavi'
```

To get numpy and matplotlib to work, i used:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-"missing module"
```

But the usual way to install mayavi is just

```
sudo apt-get install mayavi2
```

And python3 doesn't find it....

Does anyone know a way to get mayavi to work with Python3? 
Is it not supported yet?

I have tried both

```
import mayavi.mlab as ml
from mayavi import mlab as ml
```

Both give me the same error

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Traits has barely been ported to python 3, mayavi is a ways away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today, Mayavi is not supported in python3.

- http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Python_Wrapping_FAQ
- http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Python_Wrapper_Enhancement#Python_3

See also this github issue:

https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/84

Answer (score 14):

Mayavi can work with python 3 now. You will need VTK 7.0 or higher compiled for python 3 support. Then you can just install mayavi with pip. `pip install mayavi`

Installing vtk may prove somewhat difficult. You need to make sure to change the `PYTHONPATH` variable, and build vtk with tcl, tk, and python 3 support.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Mayavi2 to work with Python 3.6.4.

To set up Mayavi on ubuntu, do the following -

- Install Anaconda/Miniconda distribution of python depending on your
  needs(I used Miniconda 4.3.30). For more info [look here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html)
- Run the following in terminal -

  ```
      apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libxext6 libsm6 libxrender1 gtk3.0
      conda install -y -c conda-forge qt vtk pyvtk pyside envisage mesalib mayavi
      conda install -y -c ajsrk traitsui
  ```

  Ideally , you wouldn't need the last line since traitsui will be installed as part of the dependencies in the previous step. However, I found [an issue](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/576)  with this version of traitsui. So as a temporary fix, I have uploaded my version of traitsui into anaconda cloud; this can be used until the fix finds its way into the next release and is available in the conda-forge channel

To verify the installation start a terminal session and type  '**mayavi2**'

Comment: Python is DOWNGRADED to 3.5... So, still not working on 3.6.

Comment: @Gabs - Are you saying you couldn't get it to work even after trying the above steps?

Comment: It works, but Python is downgraded to version 3.5. Also, I've lost all the previous packages that I installed.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, normally when you're trying to install a package with irresolvable dependencies, the installation fails, otherwise some existing packages maybe upgraded or downgraded to work. But it never uninstalls any existing packages. Also, I dont know if python will be downgraded.. i think you may already have a pre-existing 3.5.x installation of python. If this is the case, you must first install python 3.6.x version from a suitable anaconda installer. By the way, what is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Elementary OS Loki (Ubuntu 16.04). What is yours OS?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I`ve found, is [this](https://www.scivision.co/mayavi-qt5-create-conda-env-qt4/). Even though, Mayavi will only work on Pyathon 3.5...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is launching Spider from Anaconda 3 and then running the file mayavi2-script.py that can be found in the directory Anaconda/Scripts. It launches the 3D data visualizer as a pop-up window in Windows10.