# MayAVI install on Python 3.6

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pyqt, mayavi

I have a very straightforward question: How can I install Mayavi on Python3.6?

I have already tried EVERYTHING, like [this](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/README.txt), [this](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/installation.html), and many many others, but **nothing** works. I can import the module, but I always get the same error message (that I don't have either PyQT or wxPython installed, but they **are** installed!).

Now, whenever I try to install Mayavi or the "missing" packages, I get the same error messages:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - mayavi -> apptools 4.2.0 -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

But if I try to uninstall Mayavi, I get this king of message:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mayavi/tests/data/texThres2.vtk
```

Any idea on how can I work this out? Should I give up using Mayavi (is there an replacement?)

Thank you all in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, look it up on github:

https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/issues/496

https://github.com/conda-forge/mayavi-feedstock/issues/15

Comment: So, so, so sad!!!! Is there any replacements for Mayavi? (Not Matplotlib, please...) I need to plot finite element meshes...

Comment: Don't be sad, roll up your sleeves and offer your help to the project; even if you cannot solve that problem, you can help elsewhere and free up the time of someone else that will... ;)

Comment: But I found the following answer (look at the last answer in this post...): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138418/get-mayavi-working-with-python-3

Comment: So, theoretically, all I have to have is VTK >= 7.0 installed... but I have, and still doesn’t work! :-(

Comment: The date of that post is 2016; the github conversations on the issue are 06-2017...

Comment: So, if I want to use Mayavi, the only way is to go with Python 2.7?

Comment: no, you can probably use it with python 3.5, the issues were reported for python 3.6

Comment: Well, I tried to install on Python 3.5, but I am still getting the same error messagens... Ohhh man...!

Comment: @Gabs I got this to work on Python 3.6.4 , please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051138/4947488 . Hope that all the effort I invested in getting this to work can be use to others as well !